# I am seeing an error like : line 11:71: mismatched input 'DATE'. Expecting: <expression>.Can anyone tell what is wrong with the query?

Tags: sql, presto

This is in presto.Also,date_trunc whether its for year or month,cannot be curtailed

```
SELECT
    dt,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE (date_trunc ('year',DATE fod))) = '2017-01-1' THEN user_id END) AS "2017",
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE (date_trunc ('year',DATE (fod))) = '2018-01-1' THEN user_id END) AS "2018",
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE (date_trunc ('year',DATE (fod))) = '2019-01-1' THEN user_id END) AS "2019",
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE (date_trunc ('year',DATE (fod))) = '2020-01-1' THEN user_id END) AS "2020",
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE (date_trunc ('month',DATE (fod))) = '2021-01-1' THEN user_id END) AS "2021M01",
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE (date_trunc ('month',DATE (fod))) = '2021-02-1' THEN user_id END) AS "2021M02",
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE (date_trunc ('month',DATE (fod))) = '2021-03-1' THEN user_id END) AS "2020M03",
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE (date_trunc ('month',DATE (fod))) = '2021-04-1' THEN user_id END) AS "2020M04",
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE (date_trunc ('month',DATE (fod))) = '2021-05-1' THEN user_id END) AS "2020M05",
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE (date_trunc ('month',DATE (fod))) = '2021-06-1' THEN user_id END) AS "2020M06"
FROM ( 
    (
    select 
        dt,
        user_id,
        
        portfolio_orders as orders 
    FROM 
        gold.user_daily_osv 
    ) AS us 
    JOIN (
           select 
               user_id,
               CAST(first_order_ts as DATE) as fod 
           from gold.prism__user_master_bi 
    ) as um ON us.user_id=um.user_id
) 

group by 1
order by 1 desc
```

Comment: Don't know anything about Presto, but your first count line doesn't have a open paren between `DATE` and `fod`.

Comment: With functions, don't leave a space between the name and the `(`...  `date_trunc(` rather than `date_trunc (` and `DATE(fod)` rather than `DATE (fod)`.  Also, `date_trunc` already returns the appropriate datatype, theres no need to cast it to a date. Then, `fod` already comes from `CAST(first_order_ts as DATE)`, there's no point casting that again.  But you may need to cast the string literals *(which should end `01` not just `1`)*; `DATE('2017-01-01')` rather than just `'2017-01-1'`...

Comment: @MatBailie can you please incorporate the solution through a code

Comment: Not from my phone, no.  It's not going to be hard for ***you*** to remove spaces and add/remove uses of `DATE()` though...